# What was the secret of Alcatraz?

Tags: alcatraz

The premise of the show [Alcatraz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcatraz_(TV_series)) was that inmates and guards who had mysteriously disappeared in 1963 suddenly began reappearing in the present day without aging a day.

The show was canceled after the first season, and I believe I missed the last few episodes. The episode guides I can find are vague at best.

In the episodes I saw,

> the inmates/guards who were re-captured were being held in a special detention facility by a group that seemed to operate outside of normal protocols.

**Was it ever explained (in the show, interviews, anything) who or what caused the disappearances/reappearances?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without wanting to spoil the ending for you, the final episode was more confused than the evil offspring of Lost and Battlestar Galactica. It was left [to the characters](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=alcatraz&episode=s01e13) to offer a mish-mash of misguided semi answers, in the hopes that by leaving the show on a cliffhanger, that the show would somehow be saved by a write-in campaign by their half a dozen fans.

> Warden James? We have a strong suspicion that Tommy Madsen works for
>   him and that the Warden is behind all of this.
>
> What's that? That measures thermal and seismic activities.
>
> **There's a theory that the jump was caused by a geothermal event.**
>
> **Possibly a tectonic plate slippage.**
>
> You call it a jump too? Sometimes.
>
> Sometimes time dilation.
>
> Unless it's **quantum tunneling or cryogenics**.

Oh, and the Warden seem to have been behind the whole thing, possibly in cahoots with Harlan Simmons. They had a falling out, which is why there's two different set of escapees, some working for the Warden and some working for Harlan.

You can read more [here](http://insidealcatraz.blogspot.co.uk/) and [here](http://www.tvguide.com/news/alcatraz-finale-spoilers-recap-1045326.aspx)

Comment: +1 for: "more confused than the evil offspring of Lost and Battlestar Galactica." That pretty much sums it up perfectly.

Comment: +1 for being technically helpful, though this nonsense answer on the part of the writers makes me almost want to treat it as *unhelpful*. Seriously? Plate tectonics makes people jump 40 years into the future?

Comment: Hey, I was one of those half dozen fans... right up until that final episode where I went "Wha?"  Just like BSG.